# Need tutorials on Content providers in android

Tags: android

I am in desperate need of good tutorials on Content Providers in Android. I have been searching in the web for the tutorials but none could give me a clear idea on how content providers work. I'll be grateful if anyone can provide me with sample codes of the projects that implement content providers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://github.com/synic/SupaCount/blob/master/src/org/vimtips/supacount/CountDownProvider.java

Here's the provider for a countdown app I wrote, it's based on the information I found in the Commonsware ["The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development"](http://commonsware.com/Android/)

It's not complicated stuff, just tedious.  [Here's](http://github.com/synic/SupaCount/blob/master/src/org/vimtips/supacount/CountDowns.java) a lot of the code I'm using to access it.

Comment: synic, thanks for sharing your code. You have no idea how much I learned from it and how it has improved my application.