# how to write a code to search through call logs' database using Android ask?

Tags: android, sdk

I am trying to develop an application to search through the receive calls in call log for a preset name or number. However I can't find any sources about where the call logs are actually stored? and how can I search through the call log at the background.
In the other word, I don't want the user see anything on the screen or have any interaction.

All the app will do is searching some specific preset name or number which has been previously identified by the user and the app periodically search the database and find those specific names from the call log database and return the date and time of call.

Does anyone know how to search through the call-log database?

I would greatly appreciate if anyone can advice me on that.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a content provider to do this. You shouldn't try to access the data directly.  The provider will give you a handle to access it much like you would a database.

For more information on those check out the Developer Site at
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

The one you want to use is CallLog.  You can find it here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.html

Here's an additional tutorial on using the contacts content provider.  Utilizing the Call log one will be very similar.  Also it will help you access the information you want to tie to the call log.  In short it is very similar to accessing a database.

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2011/05/contacts-api-20-and-above-android.html

Here's another from an older StackOverflow response with some sample code.

[Need tutorials on Content providers in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570983/need-tutorials-on-content-providers-in-android)

Hope this helps,
George

Comment: HI Geroge, many thanks for reply.  thoee two link as are very helpful to give me the idea. Do you know any good tutorial for that? all I need to do to is searching the log and finding a match name in the log, and then load the date. I would greatly appreciate if you could give me some more advice on that.

Comment: See above I added a couple of links to a tutorial and sample code that should help you out some more.

Comment: many thanks, I greatly appreciate your help. But I assume you forgot to put the tutorial link, could you please add it once more. Many thanks :)

Comment: Its there now sorry about that.  Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it answers your question.